# Using Fredholm alternative to prove a necessary condition for existence of a weak solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> Let $U = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | |x| < \pi \}$. Show that a necessary condition for:
>
> $-\Delta u - u = f$
>
> to have a weak solution in $H^1_0(U)$ is that:
>
> $\int_{U} f(x) \frac{\sin(|x|)}{|x|} dx = 0$

From the look of this, I have guessed that we need to turn the PDE into spherical coordinates and then apply the Fredholm's alternative to complete the proof. The fact that $U$ is a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the term $\sin(\cdot)$ kinda hints at that. However, I am kinda stuck there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you stuck though?

Comment: I am mostly stuck at the translation to the spherical coordinate and how to work out the adjoint. So at the very beginning despite having a rough idea what to do next...

Comment: Just change to spherical coordinates in the [usual way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). You then need to turn your Laplacian into the Laplacian in spherical coordinates.The adjoint comes about by defining the inner product $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{U} f g dx$$ and integrating by parts and using the boundary conditions to get $$\int_{U} (Lf) g dx \overbrace{=}^{IBP} \int_{U} f (L^{*}g) dx$$ Then $L^{*}$ is your operator.

Comment: Really, this problem amounts to showing $v = \sin(\lvert x \rvert)/\lvert x \rvert$ is a solution to $\Delta v + v = 0$ with $v = 0$ on $\partial U$. Then, as $v \in H_{0}^{1}$, integrating by parts gives \begin{align} \int_{U} -(\Delta u + u) v \ dx &\underbrace{=}_{IBP} \int_{U} -(\Delta v + v) u \ dx \\ &= \int_{U} 0 u \ dx \\ &= 0 \\ &= \int_{U} f \ v \ dx \end{align}

Comment: @mattos Thanks for your help! I think that's plenty hint for me. Do you want to answer it so I could accept?